# Cannot be resolved to type?

Tags: java, syntax-error

I'm new to Java. So I have a java class titled "Banks" and I'm trying to write code in a JSP.....

This is what I have so far, but I don't want to keep going because of the errors. "Banks" is underlined and when I hover over it it says "Banks cannot be resolved to a type". What does that mean? I searched and it said that types should be capitalized and I did that but the error is still there.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
; 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% 
    Banks b = new Banks(); //stuff goes in here 
    List<Accounts> accounts = bank.getAccounts();
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trying to add the code hold on having difficulties

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Banks b = new Banks();
//stuff goes in here 
List<Accounts> accounts =
bank.getAccounts();
 %>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Banks b = new Banks();

Comment: Where do you think `Banks` is defined?

Comment: Did you forget to import the class?

Comment: Furthermore, this approach ("scriptlets") is considered bad design; an MVC approach where logic is done in a separate class and the JSP only sees the results for rendering is better.

Comment: @chrylis How would I go about doing the MVC approach

Comment: @PM77-1 that may be why... This is my first time doing this kind of code so I don't really know.. "import test.jsp.Banks" is how I would do it correct? i named my package "test.jsp" and my class "Banks"

Comment: There are countless MVC tutorials found with a quick google search

Comment: There are lots of resources available. My personal recommendation is Spring MVC, and I use Thymeleaf instead of JSP (similar, but more flexible in terms of testing and such ).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:  This is how you import in some cases.

```
<%@ page  import = "com.sample.Bank" %>
```

Put is just before the doc type.  If this doesn't work search import JSP or import JSF or whatever technology seems right.

GC_